# Parameters Equivalence between scikit-learn and OpenCV (Decision Tree)

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to convert an implementation of scikit-learn to OpenCV of several Machine Learning algorithms.
First of all, do you know of any specific question/document where I can find the parameters equivalence?

If not, in the specific case of Decision Trees,  is the **max_categories** of OpenCv the equivalent of **max_features** in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the specific case of Decision Trees, is the max_categories of OpenCV the equivalent of max_features in scikit-learn?

It is **not**.

From the OpenCV [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/decision_trees.html#dtrees-params-params)s:

> **maxCategories** – Cluster possible values of a **categorical** variable into [...]

while scikit-learn [does not even support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873366/can-sklearn-decisiontreeclassifier-truely-work-with-categorical-data) directly categorical variables as predictors.