# Handling categorical column in decision tree python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

sklearn 0.24.2, python = 3.8

While trying to use decision tree regressor using sklearn I've came across common problem. I've read lots of questions however there isn't any definitive answer.

I want to handle categorical(non-ordinal, high cardinality) column however using:

- OrdinalEncoder leads to assigning orders such as 1 < 2< 3, and so on... which is a problem since my column do not have any order
- OneHotEncoder leads to high dimensions. Leading to higher depth tree and more computations.

is there no way to use sklearn? if not, what other libraries are recommended?

from [Can sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier truly work with categorical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873366/can-sklearn-decisiontreeclassifier-truly-work-with-categorical-data) it says I could use BinaryEncoding however this seems to be used when cardinality=2.

Also in R's library(tree) it handles categorical column without any preprocessing, how can this be done in similar way in python?

Comment: I think that's just the cost of using categorical data with Decision Trees. You might want to consider encoding the categories into a smaller dimensional space by doing something like feature hashing. There's a pretty nice description that can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-2-categorical-data-f54324193e63

Comment: But in R, it handles categorical data w/o any data preprocessing. Wondering if there is a library that allows this in python.

Comment: Do you mind giving the name of the function/library that does this so we have a better idea of what you're looking for?